# How to use fine-tuned BERT model for sentence encoding?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I fine-tuned the BERT base model on my own dataset following the script here:

https://github.com/cedrickchee/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/tree/master/examples/lm_finetuning

I saved the model as a `.pt` file and I want to use it now for a sentence similarity task. Unfortunately, it is not clear to me, how to load the fine-tuned model. I tried the following:

```
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('trained_model.pt')
model.eval()
```

This doesn't work. It says:

```
ReadError: not a gzip file
```

So apparently, loading a `.pt` file with the `from_pretrained` method is not possible. Can anyone help me out here? Thank's a lot!! :)

Edit: I saved the model in a s3 bucket as follows:

```
# Convert model to buffer
buffer = io.BytesIO()
torch.save(model, buffer)
# Save in s3 bucket
output_model_file = output_folder + "trained_model.pt"
s3_.put_object(Bucket="power-plant-embeddings", Key=output_model_file, Body=buffer.getvalue())
```

Comment: how did you save the .pt model?

Comment: Ah thanks that's a useful information, see my edit! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a model with `BertModel.from_pretrained()` you need to have saved it using `save_pretrained()` [(link)](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.save_pretrained).

Any other storage method would require the corresponding load. I am not familiar with S3, but I assume you can use `get_object` [(link)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html) to retrieve the model, and then save it using the huggingface api. From then on, you should be able to use `from_pretrained()` normally.